# An inner-product inequality with $p$-th powers

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $p \geq 1$. I want to prove that:

$$ p \langle |a|^{p-2} a, b-a \rangle \: \leq  |b|^p - |a|^p .$$

Rewriting this yields

$$  \langle |a|^{p-2} a, b \rangle \: \leq \frac{1}{p}|b|^p + (1-\frac{1}{p})|a|^p .$$

So maybe some kind of convexity argument could do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$ \langle |a|^{p-2} a, b \rangle \: \leq |a|^{p-1} |b|. $$

Now for $\frac{1}{q}=1-\frac{1}{p}= \frac{p-1}{p}$, we have $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and therefore by Young's Inequality (note $p\geq1$)

$$
|a|^{p-1} |b| \leq \frac{1}{p} |b|^p + \frac{1}{q} |a|^{(p-1)q}=\frac{1}{p} |b|^p + (1-\frac{1}{p}) |a|^p,
$$

since $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$.